# error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Position invalid

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am trying to develop 2 applications in 1 provider (Content Provider) but there is a problem in the code I wrote, such as the script and logcat below, I put the NoteAdaper in the first app to display data entered via sqlite with recycler view, but the first or second app failed to display the data that was entered, is there a solution to this problem?

```
public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteViewHolder> {
private Cursor listNotes;
private Activity activity;

public NoteAdapter(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void setListNote(Cursor listNotes) {
    this.listNotes = listNotes;
}

@Override
public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note, parent,false);
    return new NoteViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NoteViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Note note = getItem(position);
    holder.tvTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
    holder.tvDescription.setText(note.getDescription());
    holder.tvDate.setText(note.getDate());
    holder.cvNote.setOnClickListener(new CustomOnItemClickListener(position, new CustomOnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FormAddUpdateActivity.class);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI+"/"+note.getId());
            intent.setData(uri);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent,FormAddUpdateActivity.REQUEST_UPDATE);
        }
    }));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(listNotes == null) return 0;
    return listNotes.getCount();
}

private Note getItem(int position){
    if (listNotes.moveToPosition(position)){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Position invalid");
    }
    return new Note(listNotes);
}

class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tvTitle, tvDescription, tvDate;
    CardView cvNote;

    NoteViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_title);
        tvDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_description);
        tvDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_date);
        cvNote = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_item_note);
    }
}
}
```

Logcat:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Position invalid
>           at com.project.ichwan.provider.adapter.NoteAdapter.getItem(NoteAdapter.java:68)
>           at com.project.ichwan.provider.adapter.NoteAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NoteAdapter.java:44)
>           at com.project.ichwan.provider.adapter.NoteAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NoteAdapter.java:24)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)

Comment: did you debug your code? if yes then what did you observe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cursor.moveToPosition documentation

> This method will return true if the request destination was reachable, otherwise, it returns false.

Looks like you should inverse listNotes.moveToPosition(position):

```
private Note getItem(int position){
    if (!listNotes.moveToPosition(position)){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Position invalid");
    }
    return new Note(listNotes);
}
```